# Bucle con llamada a php esperar que termine de ejecutarse en cada iteracion

Tags: php, javascript, callback

Estimados no se como resolver esto, tengo un json que recibo de php en la variable response, y lo que quiero es recorrerlo como lo hago en el for, y a su vez llamar a otro php que tarda un poco en responder, el tema es que quiero que espere a que termine de ejecutar cada llamada a php del for, como deberia usarlo correctamente con callback supongo ? pero no entiendo como hacer.
GRACIAS !

```
var response = JSON.parse( ajax_request.responseText );
    // La variable response ahora contiene un objeto con los datos recibidos
        //alert (response.length);
        for (var i in response){
            var aqueMaestra = response[i].maestra;
            //aviso por mails---------------------------------
            var variable_post=ElDocumentoES+","+aqueMaestra;
            $.post("aviso-docentes.php", { variable: variable_post }, function(data){
                $("#poptexto").html("Enviando mail a "+response[i].nombre);
            });

            if(i >= response.length-1)location.reload();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizar un ajax dentro de un bucle es una mala idea, deberias de optar por utilizar un método recursivo:

```
//Data del json en array
var response = JSON.parse( ajax_request.responseText );
//Cantidad de elementos del array
var cantidad = response.length;

//Funcion que realiza el envio
function  notifica(indice){

if(indice < cantidad){
    //Muestro el texto
    $("#poptexto").html("Enviando mail a "+response[indice].nombre);
    //Preparo variables a enviar
    var obj ={
        variable:variable_post
    };
    //envio la peticion
    $.post("aviso-docentes.php",obj)
    .done(function(resp){
        //Llamo de nuevo a la funcion si hay más parametros en el array
        notifica(indice+1);
    })
    .fail(function(err){
      $("#poptexto").html("Email no enviado a "+response[indice].nombre);
    })
}else{
    $("#poptexto").html("Todos los Email han sido enviados"
}
}

//ejecuto la función
notifica(0);
```

de esta manera la función se va a autoejecutar con cada petición positiva del ajax de manera ordenada, puedes adaptarla a tu código. Saludos

Comment: Carlos tu respuesta fue perfecta, gracias por ayudarme a resolverlo, funciona perfecto !